Scroll down left page makes button stick but not when scrolling down screen
I have a layout that splits the screen in two, one left section (w-50%) and one right section (w-50%).
The left pane has the menu-bar. When scrolling down the full screen, then the menu-bar fixes, good.
The left pane also has a bookmark button and when you scroll down the left pane (so NOT the full screen), then I want that the bookmark button sticks.

So -1-blue is the left-pane scrollbar. And -2-red is the full screen scrollbar. When scrolling down -1-blue then menu-bar fixes and bookmark sticks. When scrolling down -2-red then menu-bar fixes and bookmark does NOT. Thats my objective.
When I apply sticky to the bookmark, then the whole top row becomes a block, "above the content", and that I do NOT want.
My layout:
<body>
  <div className="flex">
    <div className="relative h-[100vh] w-[50%] overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-scroll scrollbar">
      <div className="fixed bottom-0 top-0">Menu-bar</div>
      <button type="button" className="absolute right-2 top-2 z-20">Bookmark</button>
      <p>Some text, some text, some text, some text</p>
    </div>
    <div className="h-[100vh] w-[50%] overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-scroll scrollbar">
      <SectionTwo />
    </div>
  </div>
<div className="">Footer, Footer, Footer, Footer, Footer, Footer, Footer</div>
</body>;


This question is pretty much all about CSS and you have not shown us any. If those class names are from a framework at least tell us which framework.

@ArleighHix - Tailwind. This is the only css for my question.

@ArleighHix - updated my question, hopefully more clear now.
